# opening jquery window on html form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html

im trying to launch a jquery dialogue window on the successful submit of a html form.
I have been trying to do it like so but at the moment it's not opening up a jquery dialogue box, it just wont do anything.

Please can someone help me and show me what i need to do to get this to open a jquery dialoge box on submit.

```
<head>
<script>
function muModal(f)
{
  var form=f,
      modal=$('<div/>', {
    'id':'alert',
    'html':'<iframe src="http://heera.it"></iframe>'
  })
  .dialog({
    'title':'Iframe in a modal window',
    'modal':true,
    'width':350,
    'height':'auto',
    'buttons': {
      'OK': function() { 
        $(this).dialog( "close" ); 
        // do something, maybe call form.submit();
      }
     }
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return muModal(this)">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: If that's the entire page, where are you importing the plugin and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submitButton").click(function()
{
 openWindow();
 $('#form').submit();
}

or

$("#form").submit(function() { 
//open window
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dialog to the page somewhere:

```
function muModal(f)
{
  var form=f,
      modal=$('<div/>', {
    'id':'alert',
    'html':'<iframe src="http://heera.it"></iframe>'
  }).appendTo(f);

   modal
  .dialog({
    'title':'Iframe in a modal window',
    'modal':true,
    'width':350,
    'height':'auto',
    'buttons': {
      'OK': function() { 
        $(this).dialog( "close" ); 
        // do something, maybe call form.submit();
      }
     },
    'close' : function() { $(this).remove() }
  });
  return false;
}
```